# mime_mail class not found

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

My following code is unable to send message text. It is able to send MIME attachments. However, I am unable to send any text messages through this code. I suspect that issue is somewhere with the `$message`-variable.

```
// MIME EMAIL CODE - ALLOWS ATTACHEMENTS 
// SIMPLE SEND EMAIL PG.448 PHP REFERENCE PLUS ATTACHMENT EXAMPLE FROM SAME PAGE
// include "mime_mail.inc"; //THIS CAUSED A WARNING AND, APPARENTLY, IS NOT REQUIRED. CODE OK W/O IT

//CREATE OBJECT INSTANCE
$mail = new mime_mail ;

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
global $data, $fileX, $content_type ;

//SET ALL DATA SLOTS
$mail->from = "me@admin.com" ;
$mail->to = "ragsr@admin.com" ;
$mail->subject = "Weekly Comic Strip - Week of 6/20/201" ;
$mail->body = "Hope you enjoy your today...

  http://www.softhec.com/TCStripComposition-27Cb.jpg

" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
// include "mime_mail.inc"; //THIS CAUSED A WARNING AND, APPARENTLY, IS NOT REQUIRED. CODE OK W/O IT
```

with this:

```
include "mime_mail.inc"; //THIS CAUSED A WARNING AND, APPARENTLY, IS NOT REQUIRED. CODE OK W/O IT
```

Comment: can mailer class help me send attachments as well ?

Comment: Depends on which one, I've never worked with mime_mail, but PHPMailer sure can send attachments.